# Power BI measure with value based on slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to make a measure that shows me all future values based on a Date[YEAR] slicer/filter,

I have the measure working for showing all future values based on today's year, but I want to be able to show future values based on year selected in the slicer, not today's year.

Example: If I in the filter select 2018, I want this measure to show all values from jan 2019 and onward.

> FY = CALCULATE(SUM(ReportTable[Turnover]), FILTER(ALL('Date'),
> YEAR('Date'[Date]) > YEAR(TODAY())))

I have tried using the following for getting the slicer value, but I'm not getting it working:

```
FY = CALCULATE(SUM(ReportTable[Turnover]), FILTER(ALL('Date'), YEAR('Date'[Date]) > YEAR(ALLSELECTED('Date'[Date]))))
```

Not sure what to do here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code, and let me know If It solves your problem.

```
FY =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( ReportTable[Turnover] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Date' ),
        YEAR ( 'Date'[Date] ) >= SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Date'[YEAR] )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks! This seem to have worked, need to test it out a bit more but look great!
But without the "=" in the ">=" part

Comment: Yeap, Nice to hear it. Just test it and see it yourself. Great way to learn it. Stay safe!